# Ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять в чём проблема.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `logInfoAbout('Максим', 2006)`

Answer (score 1):

Не печатайте названия параметров в вызове функции:

```
logInfoAbout('Maksim', 2006);
```

В видео, которое Вы смотрели, они добавлены редактором среды разработки.

Comment: Большое спасибо,буду знать.

Comment: @Suicide Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.